# Understanding which tasks are running in a Dask schedular in a local environment

Tags: dask

Assume we are running on a Localhost environment and my script is running some sort of `Dask` tasks.

Is there a way to find out what scheduler/tasks are running? (since I don´t know what port the scheduler is running on)

Comment: Current workaround is to restart the computer and then run the script knowing that the default port is `8787`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out the various ports active in the scheduler by calling `client.scheduler_info()`

I would then recommend using the diagnostic dashboard if possible.  The port for the dashboard is listed under "bokeh" in the "services" key

```
>>> client.scheduler_info()['services']
{'bokeh': 43917}
```

Alternatively you can always use the [`client.run_on_scheduler`](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.client.Client.run_on_scheduler) function to inspect [scheduling state](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scheduling-state.html) directly.

Comment: Thx for your reply. I´m missing something. in order to access the `client` object I´m  opening a new terminal. When I run `client = Client()` I´m getting a new instance and not the running instance.

Comment: You will need to connect to your original scheduler.  You need to know that address.  There is no way to query the scheduler without knowing its address.  The default port on which clients connect is 8786.  The default diagnostics port is 8787

Comment: You might also consider having your scheduler create a scheduler_file when it gets created.  http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/setup/hpc.html#using-a-shared-network-file-system-and-a-job-scheduler

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for